# absolute or conditional convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I am doing an exercise but in the middle I am stuck.
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{[\ln(k+1)-\ln k]^a}{\ln^2k}$$
I have rewritten this as:
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{[\ln(k+1)/k)]^a}{\ln^2k}$$
Now $a_k=\frac{\ln^a(k+1)/k)}{\ln^2k}$, and apply a Taylor series expansion. 
Now I wrote: $a_k = \frac{1}{\ln^2k}\left[\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2k^2} + O\left( \frac 1 {3k^3}\right)\right]^a$. By dividing by $\frac{1}{k}$, and applying the binomial expansion, obtaining

$$a_k=\frac{1}{k^a \ln^2k}(1-\frac{a}{2k}+\cdots)$$

But how to proceed? Perhaps I started completely wrong?

Comment: Can you please adjust the parenthesis in the firs sum? They are confusing.

Comment: I hope I made it clearer  now.

Comment: Then there is a huge error in the second sum: this:

$$\ln^a((k+1) - \ln(k)) \neq \ln^a((k+1)/k)$$

Comment: I thought I wrote it in a intelligent way. But now changed it to the more appropriate manner.

Comment: You have to decide exactly **what** is the correct sum, otherwise it's a continue edit of the question and we get really confused...

Comment: I think it is now correct. I used traditional pencil and paper. I am not that experienced with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Using the inequalities

$$\frac{x}{x+1}\le \log(1+x)\le x$$

we see that

$$\frac{1}{(k+1)^a\log^2(k)} \le \frac{\log^a\left(1+\frac1k\right) }{\log^2(k)}\le \frac{1}{k^a\log^2(k)}$$

Can you conclude now?

Comment: I have to compare them with both of them I guess, for sufficient large n, when a>1 the RHS converges. And I think the LHS converges as well, so can I conclude that the series converges?

Comment: The series converges for $a\ge1$.